# Codeigniter active record class - get all the fields from database except one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If I want to get all the fields from database table using Codeigniter active record class, I run this query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Now I want to get all the fields except one. As the number of fields is too big I need a shorter way than typing all the field names except the unwanted one in the select line.

I have researched and found this way to do it:

```
SELECT *, NULL AS unwanted_field FROM table
```

Could you please confirm if the above line is correct and help me to write that line using Codeigniter active record class. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general it's bad practice to select * from a db, it's also bad practice to select * - 1 (For the same reasons).

If it's that important to you, You can query the table for all the fields and run a loop excluding the unwanted field to write the select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this query will not work. But what's about to get all the columns of your table by a query, like:

```
SHOW columns FROM table;
```

After that it will be much easier to write your select statement.